# I want my array value to catch an exception in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need some help on arrays. My question is that I created an integer array that has 100 elements. If the user inputs a value bigger then 100, java throws an exception. I want the user to be allowed to enter more then 100 in the array and the ArrayOutOfBoundsException is thrown at the user. I have the code here:

*edit* I forgot to ask if i got the array with a sub array correct. By the way, i want this done in plain arrays not ArrayList.

```
public class Lab6
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    {       
        //the memory with 100 elements
        int[] vMem = new int[100];
        //the memory with 1000 elements
        int[][] vTopMem = new int[1000][];
        vTopMem[0] = vMem; 
        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
        File vMemory = new File("file name and location");
        RandomAccessFile storeMem = new RandomAccessFile(vMemory, "rw");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
                for(int i = 0; i < vMem.length; i++)
            {
                    vMem[i] = input.nextInt();
                    storeMem.write(i);
                    if(i > vMem.length)
                    {
                     System.out.println("out of bounds!");  
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not a single question mark in this entire post.  also DANG.  beat me to the homework retag.

Comment: I really don't understand what your want, please be more specific.If you want that a user can try to add a 101 value, just catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in your loop instead of throw it and display error.

Comment: I don't see the point of vTopMem to be fairly honest, other than assigning one of the 2D array references to vMem, you never do anything with it.

Comment: so i can use a 2d array as a array that has a sub array? I looked online and did say I can do that. However, I got this way of making an array and then a sub array from this line of code: //the memory with 100 elements
        int[] vMem = new int[100];
        //the memory with 1000 elements
        int[][] vTopMem = new int[1000][];
        vTopMem[0] = vMem;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(i>vMem.length)
{
    throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

EDIT:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vMem.length; i++)
{
     vMem[i] = input.nextInt();
     storeMem.write(i);
     if(i > vMem.length)
     {
          System.out.println("out of bounds!");  
     }
 }
```

'i' will never be greater than vMem.length as your for loop has 'i' to always be LESS than vMem.length. If nextInt is what you're checking for to see which index you're trying to put data into, your code should look more like this:

```
while(true)
{
     int i = input.nextInt();
     if(i > vMem.length)
        throw new ArrayindexOutofBoundsException();

     vMem[i] = data;
}
```

So long as you give valid input, this will also run forever, so your while loop should be using some sort of boolean to see when you want to exit out.

Comment: I tried doing that, but the program keeps running. Can there something be wrong with my arrays? Should I use 2d arrays?

Comment: @cyberspace009, The point is, why do you want an array with two dimensions? And your program will run forever because your while loop is always true. Also, I am editing my answer to show you why you're exception is never thrown.

Comment: well I need to make an array that has a value of another array. I was told this: in order for an array to have a sub array, you need to use 2d arrays. The beginning lines of code I have should represent that. one array with 100 elements and the other array with 1000 elements.

Comment: I got it!!! thank you so much, 
ardentsonata!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for data structures that go beyond Java's primitive arrays, you may like the `ArrayList` class.  It allows you to store data and not worry about `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.  I use it whenever I need an array that will be of variable size.:

- [Tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=234)
- [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the answer was changed after I wrote the comment.

Comment: i dont want to use the arrayList.

Comment: @cyberspace009 why not?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @SomeKittens, I need some practice with arrays since I already know how to use arrayList. Also, my professor said no arrayList. I'm trying to do this as I said in the first post:    I want the user to be allowed to enter or input a value more then 100 in the array and the ArrayOutOfBoundsException is thrown at the user.